# bayes estimator of a parameter

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Hi all I have a question about bayes estimator. Basically it is based on this question:

Consider a random sample of size n from a Bernoulli Distribution, $X_i \sim BIN(1,p)$. Under a uniform prior, $p \sim Uniform(0,1)$, and a squared error loss, find the bayes estimator of $p(1-p)$.

Answer:

I know that the posterior distribution of $p$ is

$p(p|x) \propto L(x
|p)*\pi(p) = p^{
\sum x_i}(1-p)^{n-\sum x_i} * 1$

which after some calculation equals to a $Beta(\sum x+1, n-\sum x + 1)$. Then since the bayes estimator of a parameter under the square loss is the Posterior Mean of the distribution, so I have the Bayes estimator of $p$ being $p_{bayes} = \frac{\sum x + 1}{\sum x + 1 + n - \sum x + 1} = \frac{\sum x + 1}{n+2}$.

Now to find the bayes estimator of $p(1-p)$ (I use $\theta(1-\theta)$instead):
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{\theta}}\int_{0}^{1}(\theta(1-\theta) - \hat{\theta})^2 p(\theta|x) d\theta = 0 $$, then 
after some steps I get this following equation

$ \hat{\theta} =E(\theta|x) - E(\theta^2|X) $

$ \hat{\theta} =E(\theta|x) - (Var(\theta | X) + E(\theta|x) ^2)$
$  \hat{\theta} = \frac{\sum x + 1}{\sum x + 1 + n - \sum x + 1} - (\frac{(\sum x + 1)*(n - \sum x + 1)}{(\sum x + 1)*(n - \sum x + 1)^2(\sum x + 1 + n - \sum x + 1 - 1)}+(\frac{\sum x + 1}{\sum x + 1 + n - \sum x + 1} )^2) $

So I think the theta hat here is the Bayes Estimator of p(1-p). I am just wondering is it correct (sorry I didn't simplify)?

IF my answer is correct, I just have another question. I am just wondering in general if I find the bayes estimator of say p to be $\hat{p}_{bay}$, then is it allowed to just substitute the $\hat{p}$ into p(1-p) as $\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$ and declare that as the Bayes Estimator of p(1-p) (kind of like the invariance property of maximum likelihood, although I know probably there is no such thing for Bayes Estimator)?

Comment: The Bayes estimator of $p(1-p)$ is the posterior mean of $p(1-p)$.

Comment: Which is $B(\sum x_i+2,n-\sum x_i+2)/B(\sum x_i+1,n-\sum x_i+1)$.

Comment: Hi, sorry so do you mean my answer my $\hat{\theta}$ is correct?

Comment: Yes, the estimator is $\mathbb E[\theta(1-\theta)|X]$. But it is not a plug-in estimator, namely it differs from $\hat\theta(1-\hat\theta)$ as you can check.

Comment: hello Xian, may I know what your notation mean when you use B( ....) / B(...) ? what is that B here? also how do you arrive at that B(...)/B(...)? Is it some property of the distribution? thanks

Comment: $B(a,b)$ is the normalising constant of the $\mathcal B(a,b)$ density.